# Recoloring a photo in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I want to know how I would recolor a photo to make it look like the image in the link.

[image]

Comment: What does the original image look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest two ways I can think of top of my head:

Option A

1. Pen tool the area you want to paint over, make selection and ctrl+j to make a new layer.
2. In the newly created layer go to layer options, select color overlay of your choosing and play with blend options and opacity.
3. Rinse and repeat for other areas with different colors in the photo.

Option B

1. Add a new layer on top of the original photo, paint it over with a brush in areas you want to color, or bucket-fill colors in selections created by either by pen or lasso, etc. You can use different colors on this layer.
2. Play with layer's blend options and opacity.

my $0.04